# How to avoid a shell script exiting on failure for particular commands

Tags: shell, sh

The following script runs with the `-e` option, so it will exit if any of the commands in it fail:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
command1 #script should fail if command1 fails
command2 #script should NOT fail if command2 fails
command3 #script should fail if command3 fails
```

How can I make the script *not* to fail on `command2`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
command1
command2 || true
command3
```

Answer (score 6):

You could turn off the setting as required:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

command1 #script should fail if command1 fails

set +e
command2 #script should NOT fail if command2 fails
set -e

command3 #script should fail if command3 fails
```

Comment: It may be necessary in some situations (perhaps you need to take different actions depending on the exact exit status of `command2`).

Answer (score 1):

if you are running a command in shell that exits you can prevent it by running it inside a sub-shell:

```
(. script.sh)
```